# Computing the norms of a non-principal ideal in $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$?

Tags: number-theory, ring-theory, normed-spaces, ideals

$$ 2 x^2 + 2 xy + 3 y^2 $$

Apparantly these are the norms of the non-principal ideals of $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$.

Why is that ? 
How is that computed ?

Apparantly the ideals of prime norm in this ring have norms $2$, $5$ and $p$
with $p\equiv1,3,7,9\pmod{20}$.

I assume this follows from quadratic reciprocity and the norm of the ring being $x^2 + 5 y^2$.
Is that correct ?

Apparantly the principal ideals cannot have norms
$\equiv3,7$ and the non-principal ones cannot have norms $\equiv1,9$.

Again , why is that ?

I think I need to understand ideals better. These questions will help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**0. Number field properties and ideal class**
Let $w = \sqrt{-5}$, $K = \mathbb Q(w)$ and $R = \mathbb Z[w]$. We can compute the Minkowski's bound as $M_K <3$, then checking the ideal factorization of $(2)$ we find that $(2) = (2, w+1)^2 = J^2$ and that $J$ is non-principal. We remark that its norm is $N(J)=2$.

Hence the number field $K$ has class number $2$ and we can think of the ideal class as having two representatives: $P(K)$ the principal ideal group and $P(K)J$. In particular, multiplication by $J$ switches the principality of a given ideal $I$ since
$$P(K)J\cdot J=P(K)J^2=P(K)(2)=P(K)$$

**1. Norms of ideals in $R$**
For a principal ideal $(a+bw)\subseteq R$, the norm is straightforward:
$$ N(a+bw) = a^2+5b^2$$
So we are mostly concerned about $N(I)$ for a non-principal ideal $I\subseteq R$. From previous paragraph, $IJ$ is principal so we have $IJ=(a+bw)$ for some $a,b\in\mathbb Z$. Therefore using the multiplicative property of norm:
$$
2N(I)=N(J)N(I)=N(IJ)=N(a+bw)=a^2+5b^2
$$
Taking modulo 2, we see that
$$
a\equiv b \pmod 2 \implies a = b+2u
$$
for some integer $u$. Now
$$
\begin{align*}
2N(I) &= a^2+5b^2 = (b+2u)^2+5b^2 = 4u^2+4ub+6b^2\\
N(I) &= 2u^2 + 2ub + 3b^2
\end{align*}
$$
giving us the required form.

**2. Prime norms**
We have see that $N(J) = N(2,w+1)=2$. Norm $5$ comes from $N(w)=-w^2 = 5$. Ideals are either principal or not, so it comes down to solving for prime $p$:
$$
\begin{align*}
p &= x^2+5y^2\\
p &= 2x^2+2xy+3y^2
\end{align*}
$$
For the first, $p\equiv x^2\pmod 5$ so since $p$ is prime we must have $p\equiv 1$ or $4$ mod $5$. Using quadratic reciprocity:
$$
\left(\frac{5}{p}\right) = \left(\frac{p}{5}\right) = 1
$$
so $5$ is a square mod $p$. But then
$$
-1 \equiv (\sqrt 5 y x^{-1})^2 \pmod p
$$
$-1$ is a square iff $p\equiv 1 \pmod 4$, so combining both we get
$$
p \equiv 1, 9\pmod {20}
$$

For the other case, we can try to transform into the first case and use what we found. The obvious way is to multiply by 2:
$$
\begin{align*}
2p &= 4x^2 + 4xy + 6 y^2 = (2x+y)^2 + 5y^2 \\
2p &\equiv (2x+y)^2 \pmod 5
\end{align*}
$$
Now since $2$ is a quadratic non-residue, this time round we require $p\equiv 2$ or $3$ mod $5$. Using quadratic reciprocity again, we have
$$
\left(\frac{5}{p}\right) = \left(\frac{p}{5}\right) = -1
$$
Now taking modulo $p$, we have
$$
\begin{align*}
(2x+y)^2 + 5y^2 &\equiv 0 \pmod p \\
 ((2x+y)y^{-1})^2 &\equiv -5 \pmod p
\end{align*}
$$
Since $-5$ is a square and we have seen earlier that $5$ is not, hence $-1$ is a quadratic non-residue. This is possible iff $p\equiv 3 \pmod 4$. Now combining both we have
$$
p \equiv 3,  7\pmod{20}
$$
Therefore combining both sets of solutions the primes must be
$$
p\equiv 1,3,7,9 \pmod {20}
$$

Notice that $1,9\pmod{20}$ came from $p=x^2+5y^2$, which is from principal ideals. On the other hand $3,7\pmod{20}$ came from $p=2x^2+2xy+3y^2$, which is for non-principal ideals. This explains your last question: principal ideals cannot go to the $\{3,7\}$ class and vice-versa.

Comment: Thank u. Btw I Will ask a similar question soon.

Comment: @mick You may want to also note that usually the proof is for  
$$p \equiv 1,9 \pmod{20} \Leftrightarrow p = x^2+5y^2$$
Similarly 
$$p \equiv 3,7 \pmod{20} \Leftrightarrow 2p=x^2+5y^2$$
which is also the same as 
$$p\equiv 3,7 \pmod{20}\Leftrightarrow p=2x^2+2xy+3y^2$$
In this above only the $\Leftarrow$ is shown, since we assume that form and get a conclusion on the congruence class.